# Convert an Image to byteArray keeping the color

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, image-processing

I try to convert an image to byteArray, then print it on my jsp page by using BufferedOutputStream at the HttpServlet class with the following code :

```
public byte[] extractBytes(String imagePath) {
        byte[] imageInByte = new byte[0];
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
            BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));

            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(originalImage, "jpg", baos);
            baos.flush();
            imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return imageInByte;
    }
```

To print it :

```
            imageInByte = extractBytes(requestedUrl);

            response.setContentType(
            "image/jpeg");
            response.setContentLength(imageInByte.length);

            response.setHeader(
            "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + name
            + "\"");

            BufferedInputStream input = null;
            BufferedOutputStream output = null;
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            input = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte));
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int length;

            while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
```

However, the result image loses its colors.

[image: Before]
[image: After]

The problem is on the byteArray converting part, I guess. How can I solve this ?

Comment: Do you really need to decode the image, before encoding it (ie., are you planning to do any image processing on the image, or need to convert it to JPEG)? If not, this is easily avoided by just copying the bytes from the file to the servlet `OutputStream`. As a bonus, it's also much faster.

Answer (score 0):

There are two byte array conversions, one while reading the file and into the byte-array buffer and the other while writing to the http response stream.

1)
You could try writing to file to confirm which is the case.
From what I can see [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-image-to-file-imageio/), the code for reading seems to be fine.

2)
Are you sure you are writing and flushing in case of output stream as well ?

3) 
You can also try adding http response headers for content type to help the browser.

Comment: I tried to write it to file as you suggested. JPEG version is same as the second one I posted below (lost colors), but PNG and GIF versions are good. I updated my question with headers. Should I change jpeg with png ? But why the JPG file loses its colors when I write it to file as JPG as well ?

Comment: If the colours are not encoded even upon writing to file, then the problem is in that step. Perhaps you can try reading the bytes directly from the file and dumping it to stream rather than incurring the overhead of converting it, as 'haraldK' suggested